# how to set primary key in csv imported by sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have the following table stored as a csv file:

```
project_number,project_name
1,project_1
2,project_2
3,project_3
```

I figured out how to import this and show its schema in an sqlite3 database as follows:

```
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .import 
sqlite> .import test.csv test
sqlite> .schema test
CREATE TABLE test(
  "project_number" TEXT,
  "project_name" TEXT
);
```

I would like to now set the column `project_number` as my primary key and also set it to be an integer. I understand from previous questions that this is difficult to do by altering the original table, so I tried to create a new table an populated using a combination of `create table`, `create table as`, `insert into` and `select * from` as indicated [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41106/how-to-use-create-table-as-with-primary-key-in-sqlite)

```
sqlite> create table test_2 (project_name text, project_number primary key);
sqlite> insert into test_2 (select project_name, project_number from test);
Error: near "select": syntax error
```

But as you can see this caused a syntax error and I don't understand why. How do I set the primary key for tables imported from csvs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
insert into test_2 (project_number, project_name)
  select project_number, project_name from test;
```

I guess `insert into` example at https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/41108/26454 is wrong: one need to list columns after table name, [reference](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html).

Comment: Is there no easier way no set the primary key other than creating a whole new table?

Comment: @user32882 none that I know of. But I'm not an expert on sqlite. I like [Shawn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61044861/788700)'s suggestion though.

Answer (score 5):

You can also create the table first and then import data into it. Assuming a Linux or Unix environment:

```
sqlite> create table test(project_number integer primary key, project_name text);
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .import '| tail -n +2 test.csv' test
```

will skip the first header row in the file and insert the rest.

Comment: what if you're in a windows environment? :/

Comment: ah, `.import --skip 1 test.csv test` works instead